# Nginx path starting with location not working

Tags: nginx

A.

```
location / {
    try_files $uri /index.html;  
}
```

Goes to an index.html with a link to "https://apps2.mycompany.us"

B.

```
location ~ ^/ordinance {
    try_files $uri /$uri /$uri/index.html;
}
```

in the index.html I set the URL history to "https://apps2.mycompany.us/ordinance/login"

When I click on anchor in A it goes to B where I set the history to "https://apps2.mycompany.us/ordinance/login".

Now when I click on the refresh button on the browser, I would assume that I would still be in the index.html page of B.   But it 
goes back to A.  Any thoughts on why this happens.

**Modification**

B.

```
location /ordinance {
    try_files $uri /$uri/index.html;
}
```

I'm still trying to figure this part:

When I click on anchor in A it goes to B where I set the history to "https://apps2.mycompany.us/ordinance/login".

The problem is that index.html is under ordinance path. /logic has no file associated since its being set via javascript route.  Is it possible to have the following path "https://apps2.mycompany.us/ordinance/login" but have the index.html under "https://apps2.mycompany.us/ordinance" handle /login?

**Update**
If I just use

```
location / {
    try_files $uri /$uri/index.html;  
}
```

Going from / (index.html) to /ordinance (index.html) works.  But as soon as I change the history to /ordinance/login in the second index.html and I press the refresh button I get a 500 since I took off the /ordinance location

Comment: Why are you using a regex match for your location? There is only plain text there!

Comment: The value of `/$uri/index.html` is not guaranteed to point to a real file and could lead to a redirection loop. Should you be using `/ordinance/index.html`?

Comment: Why are you not using `try_files $uri $uri/` and `index index.html;` as your configuration?